# How to improve the chances of getting a free ticket from a "Blue Girl" at the Bayreuth Festival?

Tags: tickets, germany, tips-and-tricks, festivals

Later this year (in August) the world's prominent classical music lovers will converge in a sleepy little Bavarian town for the annual [Bayreuth Festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayreuth_Festival).

[image]

Source: By Rico Neitzel - http://www.rizi-online.de, CC BY-SA 2.5, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=976810

Most of the visitors to Bayreuth will have a [ticket](https://www.quora.com/How-hard-is-it-to-get-a-ticket-for-the-Bayreuth-Festival) for one or more of the performances.

But the attraction of attending a performance is so strong that hundreds, if not thousands, of young travellers  will arrive [without a ticket](http://www.expatica.com/de/news/Psst-wanna-buy-a-ticket-The-struggle-to-get-into-Bayreuth_163809.html) and without the  [money to purchase one](http://www.bayreuther-festspiele.de/english/tickets_service/tickets/seat_selection_price_categories__204.html).  These travellers will include young students and [Wagner disciples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Wagner) from such diverse locales as Brazil, Japan, China, Africa, and America who have travelled to the festival on little more than a prayer.  Instead, they are hoping to be "blessed" with a free ticket handed out by the festival's "Blue Maidens".

The "Blue Girls" („Blaue Mädchen“) are local men and women who are hired by the festival to act as ushers and assistants. The [Wikipedia description](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayreuther_Festspiele#.E2.80.9EBlaue_M.C3.A4dchen.E2.80.9C) roughly translates to...

> The "Blue Girl" is a phenomenon of the Festival House in Bayreuth.  The name originates from the traditional to 2008 blue color of their uniforms. However, since the festival summer 2009, they are uniformly dressed in gray.
>
> In earlier times there were preferably unmarried young ladies from the vicinity of Bayreuth, but now the dominant workers are students of theater and opera-related courses in Bayreuth, Germany, Europe and the world. You have the opportunity to look at nearly all 30 performances a festival season of the Richard Wagner Festival in their service and to listen. From the season 2015 are also the first male "Blue Girl" in use

[image]

Source: [TVO](https://www.tvo.de/bayreuth-die-blauen-maedchen-vom-festspielhaus-112480/)

The [acoustics of the theatre](http://www.stereophile.com/content/exploring-bayreuths-fabled-acoustic) are [legendary](http://journal.juilliard.edu/journal/impressions-bayreuth) and so precise that every seat must be filled in order to maximize the quality of the performance. And the responsibility for this falls upon the "Blue Girls". So shortly before the curtain rises, they look for empty seats and then go outside to select one of the lucky travellers (this is what provides the motivation for them to get Bayreuth -- the chance of attending a performance).

A traveller/backpacker from, say Brazil, has come to Germany solely for the chance of being selected by a "Blue Girl" to fill an empty seat.

Question: *how can their chances of success be maximized?*

It's not attire because I have seen a bearded grungy backpacker from America get selected. It's not height or race because I have seen a petite Japanese girl swoon with joy when she was approached by a "Blue Girl".  It's also not near the stage entrance because I have seen the "Blue Girls" select someone as far away as Cosima's statue (about halfway down the hill).

[image]

Source: [Bayreuth - Grüner Hügel - Richard Wagner Park - Cosima Wagner Statue 1979 by Arno Breker](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bayreuth_-_Gr%C3%BCner_H%C3%BCgel_-_Richard_Wagner_Park_-_Cosima_Wagner_Statue_1979_by_Arno_Breker_3.jpg)

Note: If it is a totally random event and nothing can be done to improve one's chances, please put that as an answer because it's worth knowing that also. Also, substantiated attestations from a current or former "Blue Girl" will be highly valued.

---

Note: the odds of an empty seat at a Festival performance are massively infinitesimal and this question assumes the unlikely event that there is an empty seat in the first instance.  Of the 30 performances each year, there are likely to be about 2 or 3 performances with one or more empty seats to fill. In some seasons there are none.

Note: there's a great video (German soundtrack, but German proficiency is not needed in order to get the gist of it) showing the 'blue girls' in action along with backstage interviews at [The Blue Girls on the Green Hill](https://www.tvo.de/mediathek/video/bayreuth-die-blauen-maedchen-vom-gruenen-huegel/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As, according to the information in your question, it does not really matter what you wear, it has to be how you behave.

I would say, if you see one of the blue girls walking around who might have a ticket, make eye contact, smile a friendly smile and hope for the best.
As so often, it will be the charm of the person they select that will be the reason to give the ticket.

If just your smile is drawing her (or him) in and not immediately result in a ticket offer, you should try to draw her into a conversation, showing wit, and being really interested in the event without out and out begging for the ticket.
As it depends on the person, you will have to go by the reactions, hoping for the best. Some might give tickets on a nice personal story, others might prefer interest in the event the ticket it for, others might fall for flattery.

Of course, all girls will have their own reasons and might be looking for a certain kind of person to hand the tickets to.

In such situation I would dress in clothes that would make me feel good for the event, whether expensive suits or dress (depending on the gender) or just your every day tourist dress, so that you can be confident and feel good.

Of course, as the girls chose at random and do not have a lot of tickets to hand out, it is hard to find any information.
There is not enough information to base a general rule on.
I have given an answer out of personal view. (And experience in being selected and passed in other situations.)